# Datagridview like control for asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I need to use something like DataGridView of winforms on asp.net webform.  If I use GridView control of asp.net, the look and functionality is really poor.
Is there anything else that could give me better look and functionality as Datagridview is not available in asp.net?

Comment: What functionality are you missing? There is no builtin control  has the same functionality as the Winforms version. But apart from that, Winforms DataGridView has for example no paging functionality as opposed to ASP.NET GridView.

Comment: Yes you are right.  I want to have moving up and down with arrow key, adding rows using code (gridview1.rowcount+=1) etc.

Comment: 1) What should happen if you click on the arrow? Note that most of this festures would be clientside(e.g. jQuery) or could be prevented by paging. 2) The GridView is a representation of it's DataSource. So change the source(normally a database table), call `GridView1.DataBind()` and you're ready. In general you won't have the same features just because HTPP+HTML is fundamentally different to a client-application.

Answer (score 1):

I use this: http://www.jtable.org/

It uses JQuery and AJAX and provides something way different then gridview.

Answer (score 0):

there are a number of 3rd party webforms controls from componentOne, Telerik, and DevExpress that may suit your needs.

if you don't have a budget for purchasing controls then WebGrid and/or plain old Html along with some js and css to spice up the UX is your next option.

remember that webforms (http for that matter) is a different experience for the user a web app shouldn't necessarily be exactly the same as the desktop and vice versa. trying to fit the concepts of on into the other means you are working against the framework, not with it.